# Unity Movement Help

Tags: unity, c#

i am making script something like in swing copters when player moves to Left to right when you touch the screen , but its on X asis , i made my script on Y Axis , But it only goes down when i touch screen , it just doesnt go up at all , Please help

```
void MovePlayerOnYAxis()
    {

        foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
        {

            WasTouched = !WasTouched;


            if (WasTouched)
            {
                if (Input.touchCount == 0)
                {
                    WasTouched = false;

                    transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (Input.touchCount > 0)
                {
                    WasTouched = true;
                    transform.localScale = new Vector3(1,-1, 1);
                }

            }
            huongbay = transform.localScale.y;

        }
        transform.root.Translate(Vector3.up * speed * huongbay * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

Input script

```
bool WasTouchedOrClicked()
    {
        if(Input.GetButtonUp("Jump") || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) ||
         (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: @DMGregory i AM newbie to programming , i can send FULL CODE of my script

Comment: No, don't do that, just get rid of this foreach loop. Use a foreach only if you want to repeat some code for every item in a list. Here, you don't want to repeat your scale code for every simultaneous touch (eg. if I touch the screen with 5 fingers, you don't really want to change the player's scale 5 times)

Comment: @DMGregory Its means that i need to Delete Foreach?

Comment: @DMGregory I just deleted Foreach , But it still doesnt go up , its just going down

Answer (score 1):

I would say it's because you always toggle the `WasTouched` flag.
Try removing the line:

```
WasTouched = !WasTouched;
```

Comment: its still doesnt help everything the same

Comment: Did you try putting a breakpoint into the line: WasTouched = false;? My guess is that Input.touches is empty when there are no touches and thus the code is never reached

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a [copy-paste error from an earlier answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/132443/unity-player-movement-y-axissomething-like-swing-copters). What the other user intended you to write was something more like this:

```
bool wasTouched = false;
float direction = 1f;

void MovePlayerOnYAxis()
{


    if (wasTouched)
    {
        if (Input.touchCount == 0)
        {
            WasTouched = false;
            direction = 1f; // up
        }
    }
    else
    {
         if (Input.touchCount > 0)
         {
             WasTouched = true;
             direction = -1f; // down
         }
     }

    transform.root.Translate(
           Vector3.up * speed * direction * Time.deltaTime, 
           Space.World);
}
```

As discussed in the comments above, the behaviour you've described should only depend on *whether* the screen was touched - not *how many* touches there are. So, you don't want to loop over every touch with a `foreach` - running this logic just once is enough.

In fact, if all you want to do is go down when there's at least one touch, you can simplify this massively to:

```
void MovePlayerOnYAxis()
{
    float direction = Input.touchCount > 0 ? -1f : 1f;

    transform.root.Translate(
       Vector3.up * speed * direction * Time.deltaTime, 
       Space.World);
 }
```

Comment: Now it goes up but doesnt go down only player sprite turn down , but not player moving down

Comment: if you want i can send you in private my script for player

Comment: This can occur if the transform is its own root. Because you've flipped the sprite, telling it to go "down" in its own coordinate space means actually going up. Changing to `Space.World` as I've done above would remove this ambiguity.

Comment: i just need something like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NdYsVifYdvc but it should go on Y AXIS, and without speedup

Comment: i am just a newbie to programming so dont get something what are you saying :(

Comment: Then ask a clarifying question so we can help you understand it better. Asking other people to write or fix your code for you is not what this site is for.

Comment: i just tryed everything i could do in that script but still can get it work properly so thats why i am asking help

Comment: "I tried everything" doesn't tell me what you need. Did you try the Space.World change I showed in the edit above? If so, what is the behaviour you're observing now?

Comment: i just added a code in my post so check that out thats part of Touchphases

Comment: Nothing in this answer references that code. What are you trying to ask by including that snippet?

Comment: okay now i pasted you code whichs works , but it Rotate my player around with Localscale 1,-1,1 but i dont know how not to make him rotate but be straight

Comment: i basicly dont need those localscales ,but dont know how to make it work then

Comment: you code WORKS veery good, but i dont need those localscale to flip my player around can you help out with that?

Comment: Then delete them. They were only there because they were part of the code you shared in your question in the first place. See edit.

Comment: OMG Man you are lifesaver , You just helped me to realease game